# Limiting Parameters

Tags: oop, parameters

Probably going to get shot down for this, but I have an issue with my parameters.

Say I need to store a race (Which I do)

During planning, I realized I needed to store things like:

- Terrain of the race
- location of the race
- time the race starts
- time admission ends.
- Name of the Race
- Types of member permitted to join
- etc

In short, it's a ton of underivable data that can't really come from elsewere
and all in all, I have like, 22 parrameters for my JuniorRace object, and like 26 Parameters for my SeniorRace object, I've already coded it but it's messy and I don't like my work.

This wouldn't be a massive problem, and it actually won't be a problem AT ALL for the users since they won't see the business model, just the view model, but it is for me having to constantly comment these same parameters multiple times.

What is the best way I can stop using so many parameters every time I make a constructor, and every time I create a new object instance?

do I just try to use less and store data elsewhere, if so, where? 
use more classes like Person would have Address and Details?

I'm really stumped here, will post my code, but yeah, it's a ton of parameters pretty much everywhere -- I'm not a very experienced OO programmer.

Comment: Have you looked into the builder pattern?

Comment: Is that a type of factory pattern? I kinda just learned about those, I googled the builder pattern just there, will read up on it.

Comment: It's a pattern that solves the problem of massive amounts of parameters by using builder methods to accept values. Let me know if you have any problems. I'll write an answer if so

Comment: I'll look into it then.

Comment: My experience with QT shows that there is really not a good solution to cover all cases. Take `QPushButton` for example, if the button in my mind is pretty far away from the default style, I'll end up calling dozens of setters to construct it to the way I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store all the parameters as a map and just pass in the map, something like:

```
Map myParams = new HashMap<String,Object>();
myParams.add("Terrain","terrible");
myParams.add("Location","Bobs back yard");
myParams.add("Length (yards)", 100);
myParams.add("Hazards", new String[] {"Bob's cat","The old tire","the fence"});
```

Then you could calll your routine like this:

```
SaveRaceCourse(myParams);
```

Maps and suchlike are great for passing around data.

Comment: each typo in the key shoots a hole in your foot.

Comment: This seems interesting, could I just store the map in a seperate class and pass it into BaseRace? oh, and is this a c# example?

Comment: where can I get Map example and/or Library?

Comment: @JohnnyMccrum #include<map>

Answer (score 0):

As I can't see all 22 parameters this is a guess but most probably a correct one.

Are some of those 22 parameter related. If so group the related ones in another class and make SeniorRace a composition of all these classes.

For example: location and terrain seem related, admission period and allowed member types seems related to admission (maybe a fee is part of it too).

This way you will end up with a limited set of objects to pass, all related info lives together and evolve together.

Answer (score 0):

Break it down by encapsulating similar properties in objects. It's called decomposition.

For example, your `Race` can accept a `TimeCard` encapsulating all the timing details, a `Location` which has the terrain and what not (maybe directions), an object encapsulating the requirements, ect...

```
class RaceTimeCard {
    private final Timestamp admissionStart;
    private final Timestamp admissionEnd;
    private final Timestamp raceStart;
    private Timestamp raceEnd;

    public RaceTimeCard(Timestamp admissionStart, Timestamp admissionEnd, Timestamp raceStart) {
        //init final fields
    }

    public void endRace() {
        //clock the time that the race ended
    }
}

class RaceLocation {
    private final Terrain terrain;
    private final Directions directions;
    private final GPSCoordinates coordinates;

    public RaceLocation(Terrain terrain, Directions directions, GPSCoordinates coordinates) {
        //init final fields
    } 
}

class Race {
    private RaceTimeCard timeCard;
    private RaceLocation location;

    public Race(RaceTimeCard timeCard, RaceLocation) {
        //init fields
    }
}
```

If you'd like, you could subclass `Location` and `TimeCard` to create specific instances:

```
final class Mountains extends RaceLocation {
    public Mountains() {
        super(Terrain.ROCKY, new Directions(...), new GPSCoordinates(...));
    }
}

final class EarlyBirdTimeCard extends RaceTimeCard {
    public EarlyBirdTimeCard() {
        //specify super constructor with params
    }
}
```

Now instantiating your Race object is as simple as:

```
RaceTimeCard timeCard = new EarlyBirdTimeCard();
RaceLocation location = new Mountains();
...

Race race = new Race(timeCard, location, ...);
```

If it's still too long, you can probably decompose more. The way I see it, you could have a `RaceDetails` object containing all the (already decomposed) details, then pass that to `Race`. Make sure to profile your application, make sure the overhead from object creation doesn't get too bad.